# Java project runs in ecipse but fails when exported

Tags: java, eclipse, libgdx

Hey everyone thanks for all the help so far !. I have finally finished this project and it runs fine in eclipse but when I export it I get this error from stack trace also any help on how this could be improved in terms of architecture is much appreciated.

Exception is Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeExcepti
on: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: File not found: assets\font.fnt

It runs fine in eclipe but fails when exported

```html
public class ConnectFourApplication extends Game implements ApplicationListener {
 
 private Screen screen;
 private Game game;
 
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  
  new LwjglApplication(new ConnectFourApplication(), "PennyPop", 1280, 720,
    true); 
 }

 public ConnectFourApplication(){
  game = this;
 }
 
 @Override
 public void create() {
  screen = new MainScreen(game);
  setScreen(screen);
  screen.show();
  
 }
 
 @Override
 public void dispose() {
  screen.hide();
  screen.dispose();
  
 }
 
 /** Clears the screen with a white color */
 private void clearWhite() {
  Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
  Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
 }

 @Override
 public void pause() {
  screen.pause();
 }

 @Override
 public void render() {
  clearWhite();
  super.render();
 }

 @Override
 public void resize(int width, int height) {
  screen.resize(width, height);
  
 }

 @Override
 public void resume() {
  screen.resume();
 }
```

```html
public class MainScreen implements Screen {
 
 private final Stage stage;
 private final SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
 
 //Parameter for drawing the buttons
 private final BitmapFont font;
 private final TextureAtlas buttons; 
 private final Button SFXButton;
 private final Button APIButton;
 private final Button GameButton;
 private final Skin images;
 
 //Parameter for Sound
 private final com.badlogic.gdx.audio.Sound SFXClick;
 
 //Parameter for the api call
 private final String WeatherUrl;
 private final HttpRequest request;
 private final City SanFrancisco;
 
 //The screen to load after the game button is hit
 private Screen gamescreen;
 
 private Game game;
 
 
 
 public MainScreen(Game game) {
  
   this.game = game;
  
  //Set up our assets
  spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();
  stage = new Stage(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), false, spriteBatch);
 
  font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("assets/font.fnt"),
           Gdx.files.internal("assets/font.png"), false);
   
  buttons = new TextureAtlas("assets/GameButtons.pack");
  images = new Skin(buttons);
  images.addRegions(buttons);
  SFXButton = new Button(images.getDrawable("sfxButton"));
  SFXButton.setPosition(295, 310);
  APIButton = new Button(images.getDrawable("apiButton"));
  APIButton.setPosition(405, 310);
  GameButton = new Button(images.getDrawable("gameButton"));
  GameButton.setPosition(515, 310);
  SFXClick = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("assets/button_click.wav"));
  
  //Add our actors to the stage
  stage.addActor(SFXButton);
  stage.addActor(APIButton);
  stage.addActor(GameButton);
  
  //Set up our Url request to be used when clicking the button
  WeatherUrl = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=San%20Francisco,US";
  request = new HttpRequest(HttpMethods.GET);
  request.setUrl(WeatherUrl);
  SanFrancisco = new City("Unavailable","Unavailable","0","0"); //init san fran to be displayed before they have clicked the button
  
 }

 @Override
 public void dispose() {
  spriteBatch.dispose();
  stage.dispose();
 }

 @Override
 public void render(float delta) {
  stage.act(delta);
  stage.draw();
  
  //Begin sprite batch
  spriteBatch.begin();
  

  //Set our on click listeners for our buttons
  if (SFXButton.isPressed())
   SFXClick.play();
  
  if(APIButton.isPressed())
  {
   CallApi();
  }
   
  if(GameButton.isPressed())
   LoadGame();
  
  
  //Set font color and render the screen
  font.setColor(Color.RED);
  font.draw(spriteBatch, "PennyPop", 455 - font.getBounds("PennpyPop").width/2,
    460 + font.getBounds("PennyPop").height/2);
  
  font.setColor(Color.BLACK);
  font.draw(spriteBatch, "Current Weather", 900 - font.getBounds("PennpyPop").width/2,
    460 + font.getBounds("PennyPop").height/2);
  
  font.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
  font.draw(spriteBatch, SanFrancisco.Name, 940 - font.getBounds("PennpyPop").width/2,
    420 + font.getBounds("PennyPop").height/2);
  
  
  font.setColor(Color.RED);
  font.draw(spriteBatch, SanFrancisco.CurrentCondition, 950 - font.getBounds("PennpyPop").width/2,
    300 + font.getBounds("PennyPop").height/2);
  
  
  font.draw(spriteBatch, SanFrancisco.Temperature + " Degrees,", 920 - font.getBounds("PennpyPop").width/2,
    270 + font.getBounds("PennyPop").height/2);
  
  font.draw(spriteBatch, SanFrancisco.WindSpeed, 1200 - font.getBounds("PennpyPop").width/2,
    270 + font.getBounds("PennyPop").height/2);
  
  
  
  //End or sprite batch
  spriteBatch.end();
  
 
 }
 
 //Handles calling our API
 public void CallApi(){
  
  //Sends our stored HTTPRequest object
   Gdx.net.sendHttpRequest(request, new HttpResponseListener() {
   @Override
   public void handleHttpResponse(HttpResponse httpResponse) {
    
    //Uses our private response reader object to give us a the JSON from the api call
    JSONObject json =  HttpResponseReader(httpResponse);
    
    //Gets the name of the city
    SanFrancisco.Name = (String) json.get("name");  

    //Parsed through our returned JSON for the weather key
    JSONArray WeatherArray = (JSONArray) json.get("weather");
    //Gets the actual weather dictionary 
    JSONObject Weather = (JSONObject) WeatherArray.get(0);
    //Finally get the value with the key of description and assign it 
    //To the San Fran current conditions field
    SanFrancisco.CurrentCondition = (String) Weather.get("description");
    

    
    //Gets the actual main dictionary 
    JSONObject main = (JSONObject) json.get("main");   
    //Finally get the values based on the keys
    SanFrancisco.Temperature = (String) Double.toString((double) main.get("temp"));
   
    //Finally get the wind speed
    JSONObject wind = (JSONObject) json.get("wind"); 
    SanFrancisco.WindSpeed = (String) Double.toString((double) wind.get("speed"));
                     
   }
   
            @Override
            public void failed(Throwable t) {
                Gdx.app.log("Failed ", t.getMessage());
                 
            }
   });
 }
 
 //When the button game button is clicked should load the connect four game
 public void LoadGame(){
  
  game.setScreen(new GameScreen(game));
  
 }
 
 
 
 //Converts our HttpResponse into a JSON OBject
 private static JSONObject HttpResponseReader(HttpResponse httpResponse){
  
     BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpResponse.getResultAsStream()));  
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        String line = "";
        
        try {
         while ((line = read.readLine()) != null) {
         result.append(line);
     }
         
            JSONObject json;
   try {
    json = (JSONObject)new JSONParser().parse(result.toString());
    return json;
   } catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
          
  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
        
        return null;

 }

 @Override
 public void resize(int width, int height) {
  stage.setViewport(width, height, false);
 }

 @Override
 public void hide() {
  Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(null);
 }

 @Override
 public void show() {
  Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
  render(0);
 }

 @Override
 public void pause() {
  // Irrelevant on desktop, ignore this
 }

 @Override
 public void resume() {
  // Irrelevant on desktop, ignore this
 }
```

```html
 public class GameScreen  implements Screen {

//Our stage and sprites
private final Stage gamestage;
private final SpriteBatch gamesprites;


//Parameter for drawing the pieces
private final BitmapFont gamefont;
private final TextureAtlas pieces; 
private final Skin piecesskin;

//this will be the sprite and texture for our red connect four buttons
private Texture redtexture;
private Sprite redsprite;

//this will be the sprite and texture for our red connect four buttons
private Texture yellowtexture;
private Sprite yellowsprite;
 
//Setup the board
//renders the line
private ShapeRenderer boardlineshape;

//setup the line locations
private int linestartx;
private int linestarty;
private int lineendx;
private int lineendy;
private int linexdistance;
private int lineydistance;

//for this game we will define a board size as the amount of lines the board should contain
private double boardsize;

//Lines required to win
private int linestowin;
private String playersturnstring;
private OrthographicCamera camera;

//Holds all the parameters for our players

//Keeps track of who's turn it is, if 0 player one if 1 player two  
private int playersturn;

//Holds the location of all of player ones pieces
//Needs to be two Dimensional to hold x and y values
private int[][] playeronepieces;

private int playeronepieceindex;

//Holds the location of all of player twos pieces
//Needs to be two Dimensional to hold x and y values
private int[][] playertwopieces;

private int playertwopieceindex;

//make the number of pieces per player variable so it can be changed for the future
private int numberofpiecesperplayer;
 
private Game game;

public boolean gameover;

private boolean isready;

private int[][] RowsAndColumns;


private int columnvalue = 538;



public GameScreen(Game game){
 
  this.game = game;
 
 //Set up our assets
 gamesprites = new SpriteBatch();
 gamestage = new Stage(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), false, gamesprites);
 
 //Sets up our font
 gamefont = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("assets/font.fnt"),
          Gdx.files.internal("assets/font.png"), false);
 
 pieces = new TextureAtlas("assets/GameButtons.pack");
 piecesskin = new Skin(pieces);
 piecesskin.addRegions(pieces);
 
 //set up our camera
    camera= new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    camera.setToOrtho(true, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    camera.update();
 
 
    //sets up our red connect four piece
    redtexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("assets/red.png"));
    redsprite = new Sprite(redtexture);
    
    
    //sets up our yellow connect four piece
    yellowtexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("assets/yellow.png"));
    yellowsprite = new Sprite(yellowtexture);
    
 //setup the board
    SetUpGameBoard(8,4,Color.BLACK);
    
    linestartx = 300;
    linestarty = 100;
    lineendx = 300;
    lineendy = 600;
    linexdistance = 100;
    lineydistance = 100;
    
 
 //setup the pieces
    numberofpiecesperplayer = 60;
 
 //initialize anything else we need for the game
 playersturnstring = "";
 
 //start with player one's turn
 playersturn = 0;

 //setup or pieces locations as blank 
 playeronepieces = new int[2][numberofpiecesperplayer]; //create two arrays one for x values one for y
 
 playeronepieceindex = 0;
 
 playertwopieces = new int[2][numberofpiecesperplayer]; //create two arrays one for x values one for y
 
 playertwopieceindex = 0;
 

 gameover = false;
 
 isready = false;
 
 linestowin = 4;
 

 
}

//Should initialize our game board 
public void SetUpGameBoard(int boardsize,int linestowin, Color linecolor){
 
 this.boardsize = boardsize;
 this.linestowin = linestowin;
 boardlineshape = new ShapeRenderer();
 boardlineshape.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
 boardlineshape.setColor(linecolor);
 
 //holds the board cells
 RowsAndColumns = new int[2][(int) boardsize];

}


@Override
public void dispose() {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void hide() {
 Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(null);

}

@Override
public void pause() {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
 
 //set the stage
 gamestage.act(delta);
 gamestage.draw();
 
 
 //if the mouse is clicked and the game is not over send us back to the main screen
 if (Gdx.input.justTouched() && gameover == true){
  
  //if the game is over and the user clicks send us back to the main screen
  game.setScreen(new MainScreen(game)); 
 }  
 
 
 if(isready){ 
  //if the mouse is clicked and the game is not over add a piece to player one
  if (Gdx.input.justTouched() && gameover != true){
    
   AddPiece(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY());
  }
 }

 //Draw our board 
 boardlineshape.begin(ShapeType.Line);
 
 ///Draw all of the lines for our board
 DrawBoard(linestartx,linestarty,lineendx,lineendy);
 
 boardlineshape.end();

 //Starts our game sprite batch
 gamesprites.begin();

 //Draw all of player ones pieces
 DrawPlayerOnePieces();
 
 //Draw all of player twos pieces
 DrawPlayerTwoPieces();
 
 gamefont.draw(gamesprites, playersturnstring, 515, 650);
 
 //End our game sprite batch
 gamesprites.end();
 
 //Lastly check to make sure our the game is not over
 CheckForGameOver();
 
 isready = true;
 
 
}
 
//draw the board 
private void DrawBoard(int linestartx, int linestarty, int lineendx, int lineendy){
 
 camera.update();
 boardlineshape.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined); 
 
 //For each line in our board draw a line 
 for(int i =0; i < boardsize; i++)
 {
  //first we will draw the vertical lines then we will change to the horizontal lines
  
  boardlineshape.line(linestartx, linestarty,lineendx, lineendy);
  
  //if the x value exceeds a certian amount then change to the horizontal lines
  
  //increment the start x position to draw another line
  linestartx += linexdistance;
  lineendx += lineydistance;
  
  //if the x start is over 1200 we have drawn the last vertical line so switch to th
  //horizontal lines
  if(linestartx > 1000)
  {
   
   //set our x values and render our horizontal lines
   lineendx = linestartx - linexdistance;
   linestartx = this.linestartx;
   
   linestarty = this.linestarty;
   lineendy = this.linestarty;
   
   for(int index =0; index < boardsize -2; index++){
    
    //increment the start y position to draw another line
    boardlineshape.line(linestartx, linestarty,lineendx, lineendy);
    
    linestarty += lineydistance;
    lineendy += lineydistance;
    
    
  
   }
  }
  
 }
}


//Draws all the current pieces for player one
private void DrawPlayerOnePieces(){
 
 //For all of player one's pieces
 for(int i = 0; i < playeronepieces[1].length;i++)
 {
  //of its not an empty piece draw it 
  if(playeronepieces[0][i] != 0){
   
   gamesprites.draw(redtexture, playeronepieces[0][i], playeronepieces[1][i]);
  }
  
 }
 
}

//Draws all the current pieces for player two
private void DrawPlayerTwoPieces(){
 
 //For all of player two's pieces
 for(int i = 0; i < playertwopieces[1].length;i++)
 {
  //of its not an empty piece draw it 
  if(playertwopieces[0][i] != 0){
   
   gamesprites.draw(yellowtexture, playertwopieces[0][i], playertwopieces[1][i]);
  }
  
 }
 
}

//Adds a piece to whichever players current turn it is
private void AddPiece(int clickx, int clicky){
 
 RestPlayersTurn(playersturn);
 
 int computedx = GetComputedX(clickx,linestartx);
 
 int computedy = GetComputedY(clicky,linestarty);
 
 
 if(playeronepieceindex != 60)
 {
  //makes sure they are clicking inside our board and that there is not already a piece on that part of the board
  if(
    (clickx > linestartx && clickx < linestartx + ((boardsize - 1) * linexdistance))&& 
    (clicky > linestarty && clicky < lineendy)&& 
    (CheckIfPieceExists(computedx,computedy,playeronepieces) == false) &&
    (CheckIfPieceExists(computedx,computedy,playertwopieces) == false) 
    )
  {
   if(playersturn == 0)
   {
    playeronepieces[0][playeronepieceindex] = computedx; //set the x value
         
    playeronepieces[1][playeronepieceindex] = 700 - computedy; //set the y value
    
    playeronepieceindex++;
    
    playersturnstring = "Player Two's turn";
    
    gamefont.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
   
   }
   else if(playersturn == 1)
   {
    
    playertwopieces[0][playertwopieceindex] = computedx; //set the x value
    
    playertwopieces[1][playertwopieceindex] = 700 - computedy; //set the y value
    
    playertwopieceindex++;

    playersturnstring = "Player One's turn";
    
    gamefont.setColor(Color.RED);
    
   }
   
   //every time we add a piece change the players turn
   playersturn++;
   
  }   
 }

}


//puts our x value in the center of its cell
public int GetComputedX(int touchx, int linestartx){
 
 //compute our x depending on the nearest line
 int lineendx = linestartx + linexdistance;
 
 //for the images width
 int imagewidth = redtexture.getWidth();
 
 for(int i = 0; i < boardsize; i++)
 {
  //if the touched x is in this range than assign the computed x value to
  //half the cell 
  if(touchx > linestartx && touchx < lineendx){
   
   touchx = (lineendx - (linexdistance/2)) - (imagewidth/2);
   break;
  } 
  
  linestartx += linexdistance;
  lineendx += linexdistance;
 }
 
 return touchx;
}


//puts our y value in the center of the cell
public int GetComputedY(int touchy, int linestarty)
{
 //compute our x depending on the nearest line
 int lineendy = linestarty + lineydistance;
 
 //for the images width
 int imageheight = redtexture.getHeight();
 
 //computer our x depending on the nearest line
 for(int i =0; i < boardsize; i++)
 {
  //if the touched x is in this range than assign the computed x value to
  //half the cell 
  if(touchy > linestarty && touchy < lineendy){
   touchy = ((lineendy - (lineydistance/2)) + (imageheight/4));
   break;
  }
  
  linestarty += lineydistance;
  lineendy += lineydistance; 
 }
 
 return touchy;
}

//Sets the next players turn
private void RestPlayersTurn(int playerturn){
 
 if(playerturn == 2){
  
  playersturn = 0;
   
 }
 
}


//check for game over
private void CheckForGameOver(){
   
 //check if player one has a connect four 
 CheckForConnectFourHorizontal();
 CheckForConnectFourVertical();
 CheckForConnectFourDiagonal();
 
}

 
private void CheckForConnectFourHorizontal(){

 int rowvalue = 318;
 
 int columnvalue = 534;
 
 
 //for each column on the board check the row for a horizontal connect four for player one
 for(int i = 0; i < RowsAndColumns[1].length; i++)
 {
  CheckRowForConnectFour(rowvalue,columnvalue,playeronepieces);
  
  rowvalue = 318;
  
  columnvalue = columnvalue - 100;
 }
 
        rowvalue = 318;
  
     columnvalue = 534;
 
 
 
 //for each column on the board check the row for a horizontal connect four for player two
 for(int i = 0; i < RowsAndColumns[1].length; i++)
 {
  CheckRowForConnectFour(rowvalue,columnvalue,playertwopieces);
  
  rowvalue = 318;
  
  columnvalue = columnvalue - 100;
 }
 

}

private void CheckForConnectFourVertical(){
 
 
 int rowvalue = 318;
 
 int columnvalue = 534;
 
 //for each column on the board check the row for a horizontal connect four
 for(int i = 0; i < RowsAndColumns[1].length; i++)
 {
  CheckColumnForConnectFour(rowvalue,columnvalue,playeronepieces);
  
  rowvalue = rowvalue + 100 ;
  
  columnvalue = 534;
 }
 
 
 
 rowvalue = 318;
 
 columnvalue = 534;
 
 //for each column on the board check the row for a horizontal connect four
 for(int i = 0; i < RowsAndColumns[1].length; i++)
 {
  CheckColumnForConnectFour(rowvalue,columnvalue,playertwopieces);
  
  rowvalue = rowvalue + 100 ;
  
  columnvalue = 534;
 }
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
}

private void CheckForConnectFourDiagonal(){
 
 
 int rowvalue = 318;
 
 int columnvalue = 534;
 
 int originalrowvalue = 318;
 
 
 //finally do this for every column
 for(int index = 0; index < RowsAndColumns[0].length; index++ ){
  
  //for each row on the board check the next four diagonal 
  for(int i = 0; i < RowsAndColumns[1].length; i++)
  {
   CheckDiagonalSegment(rowvalue,columnvalue,playeronepieces);
  
   rowvalue = rowvalue + 100;
  }
  
  rowvalue = originalrowvalue;
  columnvalue -= 100;
  
 }
 
 
 rowvalue = 318;
 
 columnvalue = 534;
 
 originalrowvalue = 318;
 
 
 //finally do this for every column
 for(int index = 0; index < RowsAndColumns[0].length; index++ ){
  
  //for each row on the board check the next four diagonal 
  for(int i = 0; i < RowsAndColumns[1].length; i++)
  {
   CheckDiagonalSegment(rowvalue,columnvalue,playertwopieces);
  
   rowvalue = rowvalue + 100;
  }
  
  rowvalue = originalrowvalue;
  columnvalue -= 100;
  
 }
 
 

}



private void CheckRowForConnectFour(int rowvalue, int columnvalue, int[][] playerpieces){
 
 
 int consecutivepiecesinrow = 0;
 
 int nonmatchedpieces = 0;
   
 //for all the rows in this column 
 for(int index = 0; index < playerpieces[0].length; index++){ //go through the row
 
  //for all of the pieces check to see if one matches this spot on the grid
  for(int i = 0; i < playerpieces[0].length;i++)
  {
   //if both of these match this is a cell is occupied by a red peiece
   if(playerpieces[0][i] == rowvalue && playerpieces[1][i] == columnvalue )
   {
    //add to the counter
    consecutivepiecesinrow++;
    nonmatchedpieces = 0;
    break; //we found a piece here so break to the outer loop
    
   }
   
   else{ //if we found one add them to our counter otherwise if none of the items
    //match then it doesnt exist in this array
    
    nonmatchedpieces++; 
   }    
  }
  
  //if the red player has no piece on this cell
  if(nonmatchedpieces == playerpieces[0].length)
  {
   consecutivepiecesinrow = 0;
   nonmatchedpieces = 0;
  }
  
  
  //if we hit for matched then end the game
  if(consecutivepiecesinrow == 4){
   playersturnstring = "Game Over";
   gamefont.setColor(Color.RED);
   gameover = true;
   
  }

  //check the next cell
  rowvalue += 100;

 }
 
}

private void CheckColumnForConnectFour( int rowvalue, int columnvalue, int[][] playerpieces)
{
 
 int consecutivepiecesinrow = 0;
 
 int nonmatchedpieces = 0;
 
 //for all the rows in this column 
 for(int index = 0; index < RowsAndColumns[1].length; index++){ //go through the column
 
  //for all of the pieces check to see if one matches this spot on the grid
  for(int i = 0; i < playerpieces[1].length;i++)
  {
   //if both of these match this is a cell is occupied by a red peiece
   if(playerpieces[0][i] == rowvalue && playerpieces[1][i] == columnvalue )
   {
    //add to the counter
    consecutivepiecesinrow++;
    nonmatchedpieces = 0;
    break; //we found a piece here so break to the outer loop
    
   }
   
   else{ //if we found one add them to our counter otherwise if none of the items
    //match then it doesnt exist in this array
    
    nonmatchedpieces++; 
   }    
  }
  
  //if the red player has no piece on this cell
  if(nonmatchedpieces == playerpieces[0].length)
  {
   consecutivepiecesinrow = 0;
   nonmatchedpieces = 0;
  }
  
  
  //if we hit for matched then end the game
  if(consecutivepiecesinrow == 4){
   playersturnstring = "Game Over";
   gamefont.setColor(Color.RED);
   gameover = true;
   
  }

  //check the next cell
  columnvalue -= 100;

 }
 
 
 
 
}

private void CheckDiagonalSegment(int rowvalue, int columnvalue, int[][] playerpieces){
 
 CheckForForwardDiagonal(rowvalue,columnvalue,playerpieces);
 CheckForBackwardDiagonal(rowvalue,columnvalue,playerpieces);
 
}
 
private void CheckForForwardDiagonal(int rowvalue, int columnvalue,int[][] playerpieces){
 
 int consecutivepiecesinrow = 0;
 
 int nonmatchedpieces = 0;

 
 //check for four to the right
 for(int index = 0; index < RowsAndColumns[0].length; index++){ //for every square in the diagonal
 
  
  for(int i = 0; i < playeronepieces[0].length;i++) // for every player peice check for a red
  {
   
   //if both of these match this is a cell is occupied by a red peiece
   if(playerpieces[0][i] == rowvalue && playerpieces[1][i] == columnvalue )
   {
    //add to the counter
    consecutivepiecesinrow++;
    nonmatchedpieces = 0;
    break; //we found a piece here so break to the outer loop
    
   }
   
   else{ //if we found one add them to our counter otherwise if none of the items
    //match then it doesnt exist in this array
    
    nonmatchedpieces++; 
   }  
  }
  
  

  
  //if the red player has no piece on this cell 
  if(nonmatchedpieces == playerpieces[0].length)
  {
   consecutivepiecesinrow = 0;
   nonmatchedpieces = 0;
  }
  
  
  //if we hit for matched then end the game
  if(consecutivepiecesinrow == 4){
   playersturnstring = "Game Over";
   gamefont.setColor(Color.RED);
   gameover = true;
   
  }
  
  
  rowvalue += 100;
  columnvalue -= 100;
 
 }
 
 
}

public void CheckForBackwardDiagonal(int rowvalue, int columnvalue,int[][] playerpieces){
 
 
 int consecutivepiecesinrow = 0;
 
 int nonmatchedpieces = 0;

 
 //checks the diagonal to the left
 for(int index = 0; index < RowsAndColumns[0].length; index++){ //for every square in the diagonal
 
  
  for(int i = 0; i < playerpieces[0].length;i++) // for every player peice check for a red
  {
   
   //if both of these match this is a cell is occupied by a red peiece
   if(playerpieces[0][i] == rowvalue && playerpieces[1][i] == columnvalue )
   {
    //add to the counter
    consecutivepiecesinrow++;
    nonmatchedpieces = 0;
    break; //we found a piece here so break to the outer loop
    
   }
   
   else{ //if we found one add them to our counter otherwise if none of the items
    //match then it doesnt exist in this array
    
    nonmatchedpieces++; 
   }  
  }
  
  //if the red player has no piece on this cell 
  if(nonmatchedpieces == playerpieces[0].length)
  {
   consecutivepiecesinrow = 0;
   nonmatchedpieces = 0;
  }
  
  
  //if we hit for matched then end the game
  if(consecutivepiecesinrow == 4){
   playersturnstring = "Game Over";
   gamefont.setColor(Color.RED);
   gameover = true;
   
  }
  
  rowvalue -= 100;
  columnvalue -= 100;
 }
 
}



//checks if a piece is already in this position on the board
public boolean CheckIfPieceExists(int row,int column,int[][] playerpieces){
 
 //for all of the pieces check to see if one matches this spot on the grid
 for(int i = 0; i < playerpieces[0].length;i++)
 {
  //if both of these match this is a cell is occupied by a red peiece
  if(playerpieces[0][i] == row && playerpieces[1][i] == column )
  {
   //there is already a piece here
   return true;
  }     
 }
 return false;
 
}


@Override
public void resize(int arg0, int arg1) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void resume() {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void show() {
 //set the processor to the new screen
 Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(gamestage);
 //render our game screen
 render(0);

}
```

Comment: Where can i find the error message?

Comment: Sorry just edited it should show the error message at the top now

Answer (score 2):

The Problem is related to that line

```
font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("assets/font.fnt"),
             Gdx.files.internal("assets/font.png"), false);
```

The file search patch (and classpath) is handled in a different way when starting applications from within your eclipse workspace.

The font is not exported (or not present) in your installed application.

1)
Try to print the file path to console or debug your application. I assume that the file-root is different.

2)
the font is not exported correctly and has to be aded to the build.properties

Comment: hmmm ok I know the font is the problem could it be that I am running this as a regular java project ???

Answer (score 0):

> **It runs fine in eclipe but fails when exported**

The correct way to export is:

> File -> Export -> Java -> Runnable JAR file.

Be sure to check:

> Package required libraries into Generated JAR.

That way, your assets will be packaged in the jar and the font will be found.